# C++ faster execution

Tags: c++, ram

I am using a while loop to execute some algorithms and what not, but it's not very fast, how would I allow my program to use more RAM? (Which I assumes is what limits it) It's currently sitting steadily at 504kB.

I am using

- C::B 13.12
- Windows 7 64bit
- mingw32-g++.exe (I don't think I need the 64bit version unless I want to go over 4GB ram right?)

I apologize if this question has been asked and answered before, but I can't seem to find it if it has.

Edit: So this will scan 100 pixels, what is causing this to take 2.2 seconds?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <wingdi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void scan(HDC dc, int x, int y, int &r, int &g, int &b) {

    COLORREF color = GetPixel(dc, x, y);

    r = GetRValue(color);
    g = GetGValue(color);
    b = GetBValue(color);

}

int main() {

    HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);

    int r,g,b;

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        scan(dc,100,100 + i,r,g,b);
    }

    ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);

    return 0;
}
```

2:nd edit: Is it possible to reduce this time without editing the code? I mean, it has to be limited by either my RAM or my CPU right?

Comment: There are various interesting space-time tradeoffs for various problems, but there is no general answer for this. So the question as posed is meaningless.

Comment: I was always really slow at solving maths problems. That all changed when my uncle bought me a larger house, now I just breeze through all the problems in no time.

Comment: Well, @KerrekSB, in case your old house was so small that you couldn't even sit comfortable, then this might indeed be the case. :D In a similar way constant swapping to HDD might slow you down, but I doubt those 504 kB were enough. Even back in MS-DOS times those were rather easy to achieve without cheating by editing your startup files. ;)

Comment: Some languages (like Java) impose limits to the amount of memory available to the application. With  C++ its rather down to the OS. That can mean the application can take as much physical RAM you have installed in the machine. However the OS itself can impose limits on what applications can consume. If your machine has lots of RAM then your problem may be improved by changing how the code is implemented.

Comment: @Galik Would you happen to have an example of improving a program by changing how the code is implemented?

Comment: @Mandera That really depends on the actual problem. For example, you could avoid branching, additional calls, loops, etc.

Comment: @Mandera Its too dependant on your actual code. If you have  implemented it efficiently then there is probably nothing further you can do. Although there are some very smart people here who may well be able to suggest optimizations if you show them what you are doing.

Comment: @Mandera I don't know anything about the Windows graphics system but that seems terribly slow. This may be a dumb question but are you including the program loading time in that test?

Comment: @Galik I am using a console application, so it simply tells me the execution time when it's done.

Comment: @Mandera I would put your own timing tests in the application itself just to eliminate the possibility your IDE is counting the program load/initialize time. **EDIT** Or increase the number of pixels and see how that changes the execution time.

Comment: Simply timing the entire execution of your program is going to be ineffective in determining the problem. Profiling your code will tell you where the bottlenecks are. The first problem is the use of `GetPixel`. That function is likely entering into kernel space each and every time it's invoked. That's bad. Also make sure you are executing an unchecked (Release) build of your program as a checked build (Debug) added additional overhead.

Comment: Alright, but I simply wish to know if there is any way I can make my provided code execute faster without editing the code itself? My original thought was that it was limited by ram, and by giving it more ram to work with it would be able to run faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program isn't limited to that small amount of memory. Since it's most likely compiled as a 32 bit application, it will be able to allocate up to 2 GB of ram by default.

So, no, memory is most likely not your issue, unless you constantly request and free it again (but even then it really depends on your code).

If your program is too slow, you might be able to use parallelization to get faster processing, but once again this really depends on your actual code.

You might also be able to use templates and instanziation to optimize your algorithm(s) at compile time, but yet again without knowing the code... no.

---

Since the edit:

The bottleneck is - as mentioned already - the repeated calls to `GetPixel()` which in itself is rather expensive, since there's work to be done that isn't cached etc.

Instead, you should copy the window contents to your own memory area and read the pixels (as bytes) directly.

You can follow [this MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183402(v=vs.85).aspx). They're writing the bitmap contents/pixels to a file, but you'll essentially want to do the same, just read that data directly. Just look for the use of the variable `lpbitmap` to find the related lines.

In short you'll want to create a screenshot with `BitBlt()` to a bitmap and then copy those pixels utilizing `GetDIBits()`:

```
// memory dc for the window
hdcMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow); 

// bitmap for the screenshot
hbmScreen = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcWindow, rcClient.right-rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom-rcClient.top);

// connect both    
SelectObject(hdcMemDC,hbmScreen);

// copy the window contents
BitBlt(hdcMemDC, 0,0, rcClient.right-rcClient.left, rcClient.bottom-rcClient.top, hdcWindow, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

// get the bitmap object
GetObject(hbmScreen, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmpScreen);

// access the bitmap
HANDLE hDIB = GlobalAlloc(GHND,dwBmpSize); 

// lock the bitmap
char *lpbitmap = (char *)GlobalLock(hDIB);  

// copy the pixel data
GetDIBits(hdcWindow, hbmScreen, 0, (UINT)bmpScreen.bmHeight, lpbitmap, (BITMAPINFO *)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

// now access lpbitmap inside your loop and later on clean up everything
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand what else would be limiting the speed of which it executes.

Comment: @Mandera Show us some code or at least name some of the algorithms (or at least similar ones). It's rather easy to get slowed down by your CPU once your algorithm becomes complex or your data big enough.

Comment: I added some code, hopefully you can give me some insight to my ignorance.

Comment: Mandera added copy & paste example code. This won't work out of the box, but should give you an idea together with the full example from MSDN.

Comment: Stupid me, forgot the link to MSDN - added it now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with GetPixel. It is an extremely slow API. An alternate approach is to copy the screen to a memory buffer and then access the memory buffer.

Comment: Alright, but what is actually causing it "to be slow", would it be the CPU?

Comment: That would be Microsoft.

Comment: So it would always take the same amount of time regardless of if I have a crappy 15 year old computer or a new one?